# Install Python 3.7,PIP,virtual env on Centos7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, centos7

Currenlty my linux machine has Centos7 and by deafault i got Python 2.7.5 and i have installed python 3.6.8.Now i want to install Python 3.7,pip,virtual env on to my machine.

We tried below link,but couldn't succeed

https://gist.github.com/wpupru/deda1cd96ea242d9a790e50cd0c97e9f

when we performed below step

```
cd /usr/src
    
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz
```

we got the permission denied error

```
2020-09-03 02:25:40--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz
Resolving www.python.org (www.python.org)... 151.101.8.223, 2a04:4e42:2::223
Connecting to www.python.org (www.python.org)|151.101.8.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 22745726 (22M) [application/octet-stream]
Python-3.7.0.tgz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘Python-3.7.0.tgz’ (Success).
```

Could some one provide details on how to install Python 3.7,pip,virtual env on Centos7 machine.Also do we need root access to install above?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it is for python 3.6 but should work for 7 as well.

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install rh-python36
```

Then create a bash using python 3 to verify

```
scl enable rh-python36 bash
python ––version
```

Then install dev tools for all the other things you wanted.

```
sudo yum groupinstall “Development Tools”
```

Got info from here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-centos-7

EDIT:
If that does not work you could try compiling the more recent releases yourself in the case there is not a package.
https://www.workaround.cz/howto-compile-install-latest-python-37-38-39-centos-7-8/